# Is it possible to form materials without chemical bonds or reactions?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, physical-chemistry

**Preface**:
I'm trying to study and think on what possible forms of life may exist near absolute 0, and from what I've read, chemical reactions practically don't take place near absolute 0 whatsoever, but electromagnetism apparently still exists, and so do nuclear particles, so despite searching the web, I couldn't find anything on if 1 or multiple chemical-free materials could be theoretically constructed somehow or exist whatsoever, so here I am.

As a caveat, IF non-chemical materials can exist, can any of these non-chemical materials exist near absolute 0?

Comment: What would you define as a chemical reaction?  Does hydrogen bonding in sedimentary rock count?

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, I may miss something with the following, on the other hand, the following may be too exotic, but I would say neutron stars contain non-chemical material, although I don't know how cold this material can be.

Comment: Could be , but it depends on whether we consider the neutrons, being held together by only  gravity, are forming a "material."    I wouldn't say it's cold, since (age-dependent) neutron stars' temperatures are estimated at  10^12 down to 10^6 K

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : I am not sure about neutron stars' temperature, as, I suspect, we are  just unable to observe cold neutron stars. I don't see why cold neutron stars cannot exist.